# Creating a New Element in Place of an Existing one

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've been creating a calender box widget (one of those little div-popups that allows you to select a date).

All's pretty much done on it short of one feature:  When you create the object, you send it a field (the field that will contain the date); because of a (really) weird set of requirements, this field cannot have an easily readable format (YYYYMMddhhmmss) and so my script hides the field, and drops a div with similar styling in its place.  I haven't found a way to neatly drop a div in as a sibling to the field AND right next to it (as opposed to appended at the end of the parent).

**How can I take a field by ID as an argument, hide it, and drop a div in it's place at the same location?**

If I could drop it, in the HTML, directly after the field, I could copy it's CSS over to the DIV (or a new field, even) and no one would be the wiser; references to the old field would still be valid, and humans could easily read the new field, but as is, the best solution I've found is to have the object take two parameters, one for the target field and one for the target div.  It's not ideal.

jsFiddle: [Full Project](http://jsfiddle.net/PacmanBits/nm3wp/4/) (I'm so, so, SO incredibly sorry for the widget's name.  It's bad even by pun standards.)
jsFiddle: [Simplified Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PacmanBits/qXWkW/8/) (Includes chosen answer)

PS:

I only have one real goal in this project: to minimize dependencies.  This widget is replacing an old one my company used for ages which, over time, accumulated a dozen and a half modifications (each in different files) and needed at least as many style sheets and existing plugins.  No one really knew what was going on with it.  As is this one needs only jQuery, no other scripts, no other style sheets...

...I'd like to keep it that way...

Comment: That's a huge wall of code, can you reduce it to the part where you need to do this and show what didn't work?

Comment: Yeah, I was a little worried about that.  I was sort of riding on the idea that the code was a little peripheral.  I'll try and make an example case that doesn't use my entire project.

Comment: Simplified version included (with answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/after/

```
$('yourelement').hide().after(newDiv)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  My Google skills must be horrible, I thought I'd exhausted all of the internets looking for just this.

Comment: yes, but 'after' and 'before' are not the most easy to identify functions :)